# Centering variable width bootstrap 4 columns in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap 4 columns in a row, and I have a variable width on those columns so when the last column is not completely filled, the boxes are slightly bigger. While this works well in Chrome, Internet Explorer seems to align the last two columns based on "n times min-width", while the columns are "max-width" in size. In other words, those columns are displayed to the right of where they should be displayed.

Trying to position these boxes with `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` does not work either, as the last box is now pushed outside the row completely.

I can't put the columns in their own row, because on different widths, a different number of items is displayed in a row. Is there a way to properly center these cols in Internet Explorer?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 33.3%;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the columns have a fixed width they work fine. This would require me to precalculate which columns might be affected, or do it afterwards with javascript. This is a less-than-optimal solution, but possible.

I have not found a css selector that allows me to select the columns that do not belong to a full column, unless I precalculate a modulo and put it in a data-attribute somewhere. I am not really satisfied by this solution either.

I hope there is a pure CSS solution for this using the current structure as-is.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 33.3%;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col.bigger {
  min-width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col bigger"></div>
    <div class="col bigger"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle by any chance?

Comment: You can copy the snippet above to your own answer to fiddle around. Or you can copy it over yourself to an external tool. There are no dependencies in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a bit of javascript to solve this issue as there does not seem to be a real solution using only css. By setting `min-width` and `max-width` to the same value, Internet Explorer 11 will position the elements correctly again. This solution can be repeated for different layouts without much trouble, and the resulting css does not become much more complicated for different fixes for different widths.

```js
(($) => {
  $(() => {
    const cols = $('.col');

    const count = cols.length;
    const offset = Math.floor(count % 4);

    for (let i = count - offset; i < count; i++) {
      cols.eq(i).addClass('bigger');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 33.3%;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  height: 100px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col.bigger {
  min-width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```